# Adding another Django site breaks existing SSL Django site

Tags: django, ssl, nginx

I have:

- Debian Virtual Server
- Nginx
- Static sites served
- Non SSL Django site served
- SSL Django site served

I've tried adding a new Django site (WR) using existing configuration files as a template. WR works but the existing SSL site (TC) then gives an SSL error when I add a symbolic link and restart Nginx.

I cannot work out why it breaks TC and wondered if anyone could help?

Removing the link to the configuration file for WR and restarting Nginx fixes TC.

Adding a basic Nginx conf file to serve a static page for WR does not break TC.

Another non-SSL Django site (HO) on the same server that was set up before TC was converted to SSL continues to work regardless.

I've checked and triple checked the various configuration files required to serve WR but cannot work out why activating it breaks TC.

Any ideas?

thinkingcomputing.com (TC) Nginx config

```
upstream tc_app_server {
  server unix:/path/to/venv/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name thinkingcomputing.com www.thinkingcomputing.com;
    return 301 https://www.thinkingcomputing.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 180m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    server_name thinkingcomputing.com;
    return 301 https://www.thinkingcomputing.com$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 180m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    server_name www.thinkingcomputing.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
#
# ACCESS LOG PATHS AND FILE LOCATIONS REMOVED
#
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://tc_app_server;
            break;
        }
    }
#
# ERROR PAGE LOCATIONS
#
}
```

westraven.co.uk (WR) Nginx config:

```
upstream wr_app_server {
  server unix:/path/to/venv/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name westraven.co.uk;
    return 301 $scheme://www.westraven.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.westraven.co.uk;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

#
# ACCESS AND ERROR LOG PLUS OTHER FILE LOCATIONS REMOVED
#

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://wr_app_server;
            break;
        }
    }

#
# ERROR PAGES LOCATIONS REMOVED
#
}
```

Comment: All those two-letter abbreviations make it hard to understand what you mean. Also, post the actual code and errors.

Comment: Show us your nginx config and error log. [mcve]

Comment: I wrote the question out first referring to them as new site, SSL site and previous non-SSL etc. which I thought was more confusing. Do you think it would be better with the domain names?

Comment: I'll get the nginx config for posting but the error logs don't show any errors. When westraven.co.uk is activated, thinkingcomputing.com is still live and working behind the scenes but an SSL error is shown in the browser when you try to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems obvious now but the issue seems to have been something to do with WR listening for and catching first the 443 SSL request that should have been caught by the TC config.

I removed the 'listen 443 ssl' from WR and now it all seems to be working. Next thing to look up is whether Nginx can handle multiple SSL sites on the same server in case I want to upgrade westraven.co.uk in the future.